# Mock import of ctypes fails with unsupported operand on Read The Docs

Tags: python-2.7, read-the-docs

I have small Windows module that relies on the **ctypes** core module. On the project RTD site the page for the module comes up empty. Looking at the latest almost successful build log https://readthedocs.org/builds/apt/2900858/ there is a failure during *make html* stage.

```
  File "/var/build/user_builds/apt/checkouts/latest/knownpaths.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ctypes import windll, wintypes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/wintypes.py", line 23, in <module>
    class VARIANT_BOOL(_SimpleCData):
ValueError: _type_ 'v' not supported
```

Following the FAQ entry https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#i-get-import-errors-on-libraries-that-depend-on-c-modules I tried to fake import ctypes using  `mock`, but doing so cause the build to fail completely. From what I can tell, but I'm no means an expert in this area, it's because mock itself is missing some math functions:

```
  File "/var/build/user_builds/apt/checkouts/latest/knownpaths.py", line 13, in GUID
    ("Data4", wintypes.BYTE * 8)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Mock' and 'int'
```

Research on the error leads to only 3 search hits, the most relevant about Mock missing (at least) a true division operator: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2014-March/235709.html

Am I following the right path? Can ctypes be used in a project on RTD and I just need to persevere, or do I need to give up and just use sphinx from my local machine?

Here is the current mock block from [my conf.py](https://github.com/maphew/apt/blob/master/docs/source/conf.py#L19):

```
try:
    #py3 import
    from unittest.mock import MagicMock
except ImportError:
    #py27 import
    from mock import Mock as MagicMock

class Mock(MagicMock):
    @classmethod
    def __getattr__(cls, name):
        return Mock()

MOCK_MODULES = ['ctypes']
sys.modules.update((mod_name, Mock()) for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES)
```

*// this is a cross post from https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/1342. Zero responses after a week so am looking farther afield. //*

Comment: How is `wintypes.BYTE` created (you've not said how you mocked `ctypes`)? It needs to be a `MagicMock` object not a `Mock` object. (or you need to configure the `__mul__` magic method on your mocked object. http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/magicmock.html#magic-mock

Comment: sorry @Dunes, don't know how to answer. I've not added any mock code other than what is posted above, as part of the Sphinx conf.py. Excepting the try: except: for py2/3 it's identical to the RTD FAQ about how to use mock. I've read over the page you linked, but it's all over my head.

Comment: as for how `wintypes.BYTE` is created, that's [here](https://github.com/maphew/apt/blob/master/knownpaths.py#L13), and included in the source tree of my module.

Answer (score 1):

Initially I thought it was ctypes itself that needed to be mocked, but
it turns out I needed to work closer to home and **mock the module which
calls ctypes, not ctypes itself**.

```
- MOCK_MODULES = ['ctypes']
+ MOCK_MODULES = ['knownpaths']
```

Thank you to @Dunes, whose comment I thought was off-track and not going to help. However it gave just enough of a turning to my mind and path of investigation to land me in the right place after all. Not all teachings look like teaching when they first grace one's attention. ;-)

Comment: Glad I could help, even if it was in a roundabout way. I should apologise for my comment. I can clearly see you showed how you were mocking ctypes. I think I must have been very tired.